# Call destructor and then constructor (resetting an object)

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I want to reset an object. Can I do it in the following way?

```
anObject->~AnObject();
anObject = new(anObject) AnObject();
// edit: this is not allowed: anObject->AnObject();
```

This code is obviously a subset of typical life cycle of an object allocated by in placement new:

```
AnObject* anObject = malloc(sizeof(AnObject));
anObject = new (anObject) AnObject(); // My step 2.
// ...
anObject->~AnObject(); // My step 1.
free(anObject)
// EDIT: The fact I used malloc instead of new doesn't carry any meaning
```

The only thing that's changed is the order of constructor and destructor calls.

So, why in the  [following FAQ](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/dtor.html#fqa-11.9)  
all the threatening appear?

> [11.9] But can I explicitly call a
>   destructor if I've allocated my object
>   with new?
>
> FAQ:  You can't, unless the object was
>   allocated with placement new. Objects
>   created by new must be deleted, which
>   does two things (remember them): calls
>   the destructor, then frees the memory.
>
> FQA: Translation: delete is a way to
>   explictly call a destructor, but it
>   also deallocates the memory. You can
>   also call a destructor without
>   deallocating the memory. It's ugly and
>   useless in most cases, but you can do
>   that.

The destructor/constructor call is obviously normal C++ code. Guarantees used in the code directly result from the in placement new guarantees. It is **the core of the standard**, it's rock solid thing. How can it be called "dirty" and be presented as something unreliable?

Do you think it's possible, that the in-placement and non-in-placement implementation of new are different? I'm thinking about some sick possibility, that the regular new can for example put size of the memory block allocated before the block, which in-placement new obviously would not do (because it doesn't allocate any memory). This could result in a gap for some problems... **Is such new() implementation possible?**

Comment: People are telling you that you can't call the constructor. Frankly, I've never, ever seen a constructor called like in anObject->AnObject();, but I don't know the standard by heart and haven't looked it up so that I can confirm that it is banned. However, if you are so sure that it is _the core of the standard_ and _rock solid_, why are you asking? If you are sure it means that you have tested your code and it works, so, if you like this solution, just go with it.

Comment: I want to verify that I don't miss anything like the last edit in the question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't get sucked in by the FQA troll. As usual he gets the facts wrong.

You can certainly call the destructor directly, for all objects whether they are created with placement new or not. Ugly is in the eye of the beholder, it is indeed rarely needed, but the only hard fact is that both memory allocation and object creation must be balanced.

"Regular" new/delete simplifies this a bit by tying memory allocation and object creation together, and stack allocation simplifies it even further by doing both for you.

However, the following is perfectly legal:

```
int foo() {
    CBar bar;
    (&bar)->~CBar();
    new (&bar) CBar(42);
 }
```

Both objects are destroyed, and the stack memory is automatically recycled too. yet unlike the FQA claims, the first call of the destructor is not preceded by placement new.

Comment: Do you think it's possible, that the in-placement and non-in-placement implementation of new can differ? I'm thinking about some sick possibility, that regular new can for example put size of the memory block allocated before the block, and in-placement new obviously not (because it doesn't allocate any memory). This could result in a gap for some problems...

Comment: It doesn't matter how they differ. The implementation has to make sure my code above works, because that is conforming. Pixie dust is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's rational.

Comment: MSalters, maybe you'll be interested: a generic resetting mixin / function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133738/more-generic-resetable-mixin

Comment: Why `(&bar)->~CBar();` instead of `bar.~CBar();`?

Comment: @Zero: Both are legal and do the same, but the question originally used `->~` so I didn't change that.

Comment: It's actually not ugly in case of a union, if a union members requires to be constructed or destructed.

Comment: @galinette: True now, but the question predates C++11.

Comment: i dont really get the last sentence. does the fqa claim that the first call of the destructor is preceded by placement new?

Comment: @user463035818: I consider the FQA author to be a troll. He's  suggesting that's how it works, but he knows enough about C++ not to say it outright.

Answer (score 20):

Why not implement a Clear() method, that does whatever the code in the body of the destructor does? The destructor then just calls Clear() and you call Clear() directly on an object to "reset it".

Another option, assuming your class supports assignment correctly:

```
MyClass a;
...
a = MyClass();
```

I use this pattern for resetting std::stack instances, as the stack adaptor does 
not provide a clear function.

Comment: Because it would require to maintain the Clear() method correctness.

Comment: You have to maintain the destructor "correctness" - I'm suggesting moving the destructor code into the Clear() method, so the destructor only contains a single call to Clear(). I write almost all my own code this way, BTW.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to implement "destructive" Clear() method? It would have to free any heap allocated members when called from destructor. But when called as a reset-like method, it would have to only clear such members and leave them usable. This would require to implement Init() method and call it from constructor. Reset method would call Clear() and then Init(). Init methods look like non-RAII code. And what when multiple constructors are needed? This can complicate things.

Comment: It depends on the class's semantics. If rebuilding the class after clear is expensive, then use my second suggestion. I would say that either is likely to be less complicated than messing about with explicit destructor calls and use of placement new.

Answer (score 12):

Technically it is bad practice to call constructors or destructors explicitly.

The delete keyword ends up calling them when you use it. Same goes for new with constructors.

I'm sorry but that code makes me want to tear my hair out. You should be doing it like this:

### Allocate a new instance of an object

```
AnObject* anObject = new AnObject();
```

### Delete an instance of an object

```
delete anObject;
```

NEVER do this:

```
anObject->~AnObject(); // My step 1.
free(anObject)
```

If you must "reset" an object, either create a method which clears all the instance variables inside, or what I would recommend you do is Delete the object and allocate yourself a new one.

> "It is the core of the language?"

That means nothing. Perl has about six ways to write a for loop. Just because you CAN do things in a language because they are supported does mean you should use them. Heck I could write all my code using **for switch** statements because the "Core" of the language supports them. Doesn't make it a good idea.

Why are you using **malloc** when you clearly don't have to. Malloc is a C method.

**New and Delete are your friends in C++**

### "Resetting" an Object

```
myObject.Reset();
```

There you go. This way saves you from needlessly allocating and deallocating memory in a dangerous fashion. Write your Reset() method to clear the value of all objects inside your class.

Comment: I want to reset my object and I rely on core of the C++ standard. What's wrong with that?

Comment: The Reset() method requires maintenance.

Comment: If you wrote all your code the way you are proposing, I'd say your entire codebase would need maintenance

Comment: Technically, you should change the second line of the "NEVER do this" part to `delete anObject` because `free()` doesn't call destructors

Comment: You can implement Reset with destructor call and a placement new.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot call the constructor in the manner indicated by you. Instead, you can do so using placement-new (like your code also indicates):

```
new (anObject) AnObject();
```

This code is guaranteed to be well-defined if the memory location is still available – as it should be in your case.

(I've deleted the part about whether this is debatable code or not – it's well-defined. Full stop.)

By the way, Brock is right: how the implementation of `delete` isn't fixed – it is *not* the same as calling the destructor, followed by `free`. Always pair calls of `new` and `delete`, never mix one with the other: *that's* undefined.

Comment: @Mehrdad: what `&`? :o) Seriously: thanks; I forgot that `anObject` was already a pointer.

Comment: But if I need it (because the pointer to object being reset is keep in very long queue, which I don't want to parse), then there is obviously no problem, right?

Comment: Just to add to this answer: The whole reason placement new exists is because you can't call a constructor directly.

Comment: So what would happen if the placement new ctor call throws an exception? The memory won't get released, but the object isn't constructed either, so we can't call delete ourselves.

Comment: @jalf: if constructors throw exception, they need to clear up what they've already created – *always*, not just with placement new. After that, we don't need, and in fact mustn't, call `delete` on the object.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, what you are doing is valid most of the time. [[basic.life]p8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8) says:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied, and
> - the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and
> - neither the original object nor the new object is a potentially-overlapping subobject ([intro.object]).

So it is legal if you don't have a `const` or reference member.

If you don't have this guarantee, you need to use `std::launder` or use the pointer returned by placement new (like you're doing anyways) if you want to use the new object:

```
// no const/ref members
anObject->~AnObject(); // destroy object
new (anObject) AnObject(); // create new object in same storage, ok

anObject->f(); // ok

// const/ref members
anObject->~AnObject();
auto newObject = new (anObject) AnObject();

anObject->f(); // UB
newObject->f(); // ok
std::launder(anObject)->f(); // ok
```

Comment: [C++ draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8) was updated. The requirements for a class not to have reference or const members was removed. It seems that we do not need `std::launder` now. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Storage_reuse) doesn't mention reference and const members as well.

Comment: I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72250710/5447906) for clarification which version of the standard this applies to.

Answer (score 6):

Note that they're not `malloc` and `free` that are used, but `operator new` and `operator delete`. Also, unlike your code, by using new you're guaranteeing exception safety. The nearly equivalent code would be the following.

```
AnObject* anObject = ::operator new(sizeof(AnObject));
try
{
    anObject = new (anObject) AnObject();
}
catch (...)
{
    ::operator delete(anObject);
    throw;
}

anObject->~AnObject();
::operator delete(anObject)
```

The reset you're proposing is valid, but not idiomatic. It's difficult to get right and as such is generally frowned upon and discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Why not reset using the operator=()? This is not debatable and by far more readable.

```
A a;
//do something that changes the state of a
a = A(); // reset the thing
```

Comment: It is true to a large degree, except it just doesn't work if the object is unmovable  :: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee95f3077192621f  . If you have a solution, please send help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call the constructor like that, but there's nothing wrong with reusing the memory and calling placement new, as long you *don't* delete or free (deallocate) the memory. I must say reseting an object like this is a little sketchy. I would write an object to be explicitly resetable, or write a swap method and use that to reset it.

E.g.

```
anObject.swap( AnObject() ); // swap with "clean" object
```

Comment: This is the only real alternative IMO -- HandleBody + swap() with temporary.

Answer (score 3):

If your object has sensible assignment semantics (and correct operator=), then *anObject = AnObject() makes more sense, and is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It is far better just to add something like a Reset() method to your object rather than play with placement new's.

You are exploiting the placement new feature which is intended to allow you to control where an object is allocated.  This is typically only an issue if your hardware has "special" memory like a flash chip.  IF you want to put some objects in the flash chip, you can use this technique.  The reason that it allows you to explicitly call the destructor is that YOU are now in control of the memory, so the C++ compiler doesn't know how to do the deallocation part of the delete.

It is not saving you much code either, with a reset method, you will have to set the members to their starting values.  malloc() doesn't do that so you are going to have to write that code in the constructor anyway.  Just make a function that sets your members to the starting values, call it Reset() call it from the constructor and also from anywhere else you need.

Comment: The real alternative is the HandleBody idiom and swap() method. Reset method is considered harmful by me -- it requires careful maintenance.