# Destroy and then construct new object using the same variable

Tags: c++, placement-new

Sometimes it's nice to start over. In C++ I can employ this following simple manoeuvre:

```
{

    T x(31, Blue, false);

    x.~T();                        // enough with the old x

    ::new (&x) T(22, Brown, true); // in with the new!

    // ...
}
```

At the end of the scope, the destructor will run once again and all seems well. (Let's also say `T` is a bit special and doesn't like being assigned, let alone swapped.) But something tells me that it's not always without risk to destroy everything and try again. Is there a possible catch with this approach?

Comment: Why the heck would you want to do this?

Comment: This is a whimsical approach to pedagogy.

Comment: What's wrong with just `x = T(22, Brown, true);`?

Comment: It's well known idiom. `31` and `22` are ages, `Blue` and `Brown` - color of the eyes, `false` and `true` - either `love`, but most likely breasts. Bottom line, somewhere along the lines (of your code) your new girlfriend will become `x` too.

Comment: @AzzA: I was literally just picking standard type and variable names and some random integers from the lazy end of my keyboard and random bools.. does this say more about my subconsciousness or about you now? :-S

Comment: @AzzA: And what if `31` and `22` refer to the number of tentacles, `Blue` and `Brown` to the skin color, and `false` and `true` are about having the idea of conquering human-kind?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Oh, `T` doesn't have an ass. operator. Let me edit.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, I guess we are both in trouble then. But I cannot see how it can be read differently... or typed by an accident ;)

Comment: Of course `T` doesn't like being assigned.. It doesn't want to become another `T`, it just wants a fresh start!

Comment: @Xeo, You obviously didn't see author's comments next to code. Not to mention his choice of local variable name and the fact that he subconsciously ALREADY prepared to fail - he is creating new girlfriend at the old one's address... How silly is that?

Comment: Why not `T x(31, Blue, false); T y(22, Brown, true); std::swap(x, y);` ?

Comment: @AzzA: You're right, maybe I *am* subconsciously treating objects like women...

Comment: @Kerrek: hmmm... better than treating women like objects.  But, I can see why you have to be worried about them throwing things.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: if `T` is not assignable `std::swap` will likely fail (we can't assume that it has a custom swap). Besides for a generic class don't you mean `using std::swap; swap(x, y)`.

Comment: @Grizzly: Keep in mind in C++11, `std::swap(x, y)` is required to have the same behavior as `using std::swap; swap(x, y);`, so we can stop worrying. :)

Comment: @GMan: It is? I didn't know that. Can you tell me where in the standard that behaviour is mandated? Not that I don't trust you, but I would like to verify for myself.

Comment: @Grizzly: §17.6.3.2/3. In the meantime, `boost::swap` does the same.

Comment: @GMan: As far as I can tell that section says nothing of that sort. As I understand it, it says that `a` and `b` are considered swappable if `swap(a, b)` is valid in a context where `std::swap` can be called unqualified. Considering that the examples in the section show `using std::swap; swap(t1, t2);` for how to ensure the proper evaluation context and that `§20.2.2` doesn't mention any such behavior your statement doesn't seem to be correct (I might be wrong of course). `boost::swap` behaves that way, though I wouldn't include boost just for that (unless I already use it in the code).

Comment: @Grizzly: Just read the first sentence of paragraph three: "The context in which `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are evaluated shall ensure that a binary non-member function named “`swap`” is selected via overload resolution". This is a requirement of the standard library. The standard is saying, "Your implementation of the standard library better find a binary non-member `swap` if it exists when you call `swap(t, u)`. (And paragraph two says that swappable types are to be called with unqualified `swap`, not `std::swap`.)

Comment: @Grizzly: And just because I'm lame, [here's an argument from authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2684544/87234) (in the comments). It's been the intention for a long time that `std::swap` internally searches for `swap(t, u)` with ADL.

Comment: @GMan:The paragraph basically states that when the standard library uses `swap` it shall search for one using ADL (meaning it has to call it as `swap(t, u)` instead of `::std::swap(t, u)` or some `__Swap(t, u)`). That doesn't mean that `std::swap` will internally use ADL to find an existing `swap`. From the text and particulary the examples in the standard I'm pretty sure it doesn't. The provided link doesn't say anything about such a behaviour of `std::swap` either, only about using `swap` in the library. Changing that behaviour would be like a pretty sever break in backward compatibility.

Comment: @Grizzly: I don't think that's right. Perhaps I'll ask a question.

Comment: @Grizzly: [I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170247/does-c11-change-the-behavior-of-explicitly-calling-stdswap-to-ensure-adl-loc). You do seem to be correct on further review, which makes me sad two-fold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call destructor and then constructor (resetting an object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124634/call-destructor-and-then-constructor-resetting-an-object)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the only way to make this really safe to use is to require the called constructor to be `noexcept`, for example by adding a `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(noexcept(T(22, Brown, true)), "The constructor must be noexcept for inplace reconstruction");
T x(31, Blue, false);
x.~T();
::new (&x) T(22, Brown, true);
```

Of course this will only work for C++11.

Comment: Very nice use of `noexcept` - I never realized it could be used interrogatively!

Comment: You could package the `static_assert`, pseudo-destructor call, and placement new all into one `reconstruct` function, using perfect forwarding for the last step. But I still think it's awful form.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for classes that have const or reference members: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50221156/5447906). At least until C++20: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72250913/5447906).

Answer (score 17):

If `T`'s constructor throws on the second construction, you got a problem. If you like brute-force approaches, check this:

```
T x(31, Blue, false);
x.~T();
const volatile bool _ = true;
for(;_;){
  try{
    ::new (&x) T(22, Brown, true);
    break; // finally!
  }catch(...){
    continue; // until it works, dammit!
  }
}
```

It even provides the strong exception guarantee!

---

On a more serious note, it's like stepping on a landmine, knowing it will go off if you move your foot...

And there actually *is* a way around the undefined behaviour of the double destruction here:

```
#include <cstdlib>

T x(31, Blue, false);
x.~T();
try{
  ::new (&x) T(22, Brown, true);
}catch(...){
  std::exit(1); // doesn't call destructors of automatic objects
}
```

Comment: Hmm... and the landmine would be a class which throws on every but its first constructor call!

Comment: Of course depending on your type T this might loop on for all eternity (if the constructor always throws for those arguments), so it's "safe for certain definitions of safe" (strong guarantee or not I'm not convinced I'd like that in my code)

Comment: My usual workaround was to make an aligned buffer and placement new to start.  Then you avoid the automatic destruction if the re-construction fails, avoiding the pitfall.

Comment: Why use `_` at all? `for(;;)` is defined to be an infinite loop.

Comment: @GMan: That part was meant as more of a humorous answer, that's why the `(;_;)` emoticon. :) Also, a `_` macro would be reserved for the implementation. :(

Comment: @Xeo: I see, carry on. :) ☆☆☆

Comment: @Xeo: I don't think `_` is reserved for the implementation; it neither matches `_[A-Z]` nor `__`. Cf. the `_1` placeholders from Boost and C++11

Comment: @MSalters: Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace / scope (aka macros).

Comment: @Xeo: Macros have their own separate namespace (§16.3/7); this is different from the global namespace accessed by `::` (§3.3.6/3). It's not so clear to me whether these macro names are reserved, or just likely to break an implementation's extensions to the Standard. (The Standard does not define any such names, and if it did, they would be protected by §17.6.4.3.1/1.)

Answer (score 9):

If T's construction expression throws, you will double destruct the object, which is UB. Of course, even the desire to do this is indicative of a design failure.

Comment: Design failure, or moral failure?

Comment: @Crashworks: Rather, self-esteem failure. You know, starting over and such... ;)

Comment: A question: It seems like a call to ~T() is special in that it will (obviously) call any code you've explicitly put in your destructor, and will also do a lot of automatic destruction of stuff? I had previously thought that the automatic stuff just happened around `delete` and and the end of the scope? Something new learned.

Comment: @Aaron `delete` invokes the destructor and then releases allocated memory. Calling `~T()` explicitly only invokes the destructor (there is no allocated memory to release in the example). Doing this sidesteps normal automatic storage semantics, so the destructor will still be called anyway when control leaves the scope, even though you already called it manually.

Comment: I understand that. By 'automatic destruction of stuff' I meant calling the destructors of data members. A call to `delete` does three things, (1) execute the code you have written inside `~T()`, (2) calls destructors on data members, and (3) frees the memory. I was surprised that, if you explicitly call `~T()`, that you get (1) *and* (2). I had thought you would just get (1).

Comment: @Aaron: definitely 1 and 2.  Of course 2 also covers base class destruction if necessary (and associated implementation steps like VDT-pointer restoration to pre-derived-class-construction states as it works its way up the hierarchy towards the base classes).

Comment: I had thought that the compiler might sneak in another special function (call it `~~T`, for arguments sake) into the vtables and so on. I thought that this function would walk up the chain, do the automatic destruction of members, calling `~T` on the way. And that `~~T` would be called by `delete` and also when things go out of scope. .... OK, I'll admit, I didn't really think about it that much prior to seeing this question :-) .

Answer (score 7):

I tried to compile it, but I only dared to run it under debugger. So I took a look at disassembly my old compiler generated (comments are compiler's too):

```
@1 sub nerve.cells, fa0h
@2 xor x, x     // bitch.
@3 mov out, x
@4 test out, out
@5 jne @1
@6 xor x, x     // just in case.
@7 sub money, 2BC   // dammit.
@8 mov %x, new.one
@8 cmp new.one, %x 
@9 jne @7   
...
@25 jmp @1      // sigh...
```

Answer (score 2):

Mmm. Since you're doing everything that C++ discourages, I think everyone is forgetting about **goto**.

Note that after the explicit `X.~T()` call, and before it is reconstructed<sup>1</sup>, there would still be double destruction if someone did a `goto` to before the declaration/initialization of the variable x (*even within the inner scope block*).

Since you could obviously just document that, I won't go through the hassle of trying to 'fix' this. You could, conceptually, design a RAII class to manages object re-construction in-place, making this manoeuvre safe for goto's in any place. Note that you could have the placement-new constructor call get perfectly forwarded from the RAII manager object's destructor.  Life is good.

The other caveats still apply, of course (see other answers)

---

<sup>1</sup> we can assume nothrow constuction for this moment

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to stop you doing this, it will work in most cases. But as is the case in a lot of C++ knowing the specifics of your your cases will be the difference between it working as you want and a core dump. There are very few example of reasons I could see why you would want to do this in a real program, the only one that make sense is a memory mapped file.