# Is it possible to destroy and re-create an object this way?

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get a fresh start in C++ without failing again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829548/can-i-get-a-fresh-start-in-c-without-failing-again)

Consider `T* o = new(T())`, where T has a copy constructor defined. Also suppose expression `new` uses the default `::operator new()`

To re-use the memory allocated for o, instead of deleting the object with `delete o`, does the standard allow the following sequence:

1. call `o->~T()` explicitly
2. use placement new for creating a copy of an object on the memory allocated for o previously: new(o) T(x)
3. when done with o and its memory, delete it with the `delete o`

I also ask this because I don't understand why `std::map<T, V>` (or its `operator[]` specifically), for example, requires T to have an appropriate assignment operator defined, if the above sequence could work without this requirement. I doubt that map has been designed this way just because `operator=()` and the copy constructor can have different semantics, since most of the time they are just implemented the same way.

Comment: Exception safety is the answer to your `map` question.

Comment: @Xeo Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: If you do this and the constructor fails (in step 2), the existing object is already gone. A similar situation was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829548/can-i-get-a-fresh-start-in-c-without-failing-again).

Comment: @Martinho In my case the object is not allocated on the stack, so I know whether it is safe to delete it or not in step 3.

Comment: @Martin: remember that step 3 can happen long after this operation: in a map, that happens when the map is destroyed. Unless you want the failed construction of a new element to result in removal of existing ones.