# Why doesn't default assignment operator call the destructor first?

Tags: c++

So in the following example, we cause class `Foo` to replace itself with `*this = Foo()`.  I'm glad I just tested this because it turns out in this circumstance, the destructor of the old `Foo` doesn't get called.  I guess that's because the default assignment operator just uses `memcpy` ... but as a language design question ... why wouldn't you make the default assignment operator destroy the assigned-to object first to prevent accidents?

http://codepad.org/9WCo6yZ5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MustBeDestroyed //(for some reason not shown here)
{
public:
  int i;
  MustBeDestroyed(int i) : i(i) {}
  ~MustBeDestroyed() { cout << "destroyed contained class " << i << endl; }
};

class Foo
{
public:
  MustBeDestroyed x;
  Foo(int y) : x(y) {}
  void replace_myself(int y) { Foo f(y); *this=f; }
  void print() { cout << "This is outer/inner class " << x.i << endl; }
  ~Foo() { cout << "destroyed outer class " << x.i << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo a(1);
  a.print();
  a.replace_myself(2);
  a.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What accidents? Assignment is just that - assigns a new value to an old value.

Comment: The default assignment operator does not use memcpy (although a compiler optimization could result in that). It is a memberwise assignment.

Comment: `int i, j; i = 5; j = i;` are you saying that it is sensible to expect that I can't use `i` anymore? I disagree.

Comment: Five downvotes for a reasonably worded question with code example?  The hate is strong today!  -> suicide booth ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would assignment call the destructor? It does exactly what is says it does: It calls the assignment operator. The compiler generated assignment operator simply does the obvious: assignment of all members from the old obejct to the new (using their assignment operation). Nothing more, nothing less. This is exactly the reason for the famous [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Now as to why it doesn't call the destructor:  That would end the lifetime of the object. While it is theoretically possibly to construct a new object inplace of the old one, that approach is typically incorrect in the face of exception ([look at this question for more about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829548/can-i-get-a-fresh-start-in-c-without-failing-again)), so it can't be used in the general case. Besides if it did the approach you proposed, it wouldn't call the assignment operators for the members, but destructor/copy constructor instead. That means that custom assignment behaviour (which doesn't actually need to be the same as copy behaviour) would not be honored.

Comment: Assignment would call the destructor first to avoid a memory leak if the value being overwritten contained a ptr to data off the heap. If you simply overwrite the ptr, then you leak memory. Thus the built-in assignment operator should be overridden in this case (since the built-in will leak).

Comment: Exactly, I once saw that one of the first implementations of `std::vector` actually called the destructor and later placement new. I think this is inefficient (pessimistic), doesn't have the strong-exception-guarantee and it looks just wrong. Of course we learned to write better C++ from those days.

Answer (score 8):

Because destroying the object first would end the lifetime. Then you would have to invoke a constructor to start the new object's lifetime. But the behavior of operator= isn't to destroy the current object and create another, but to assign a new value to the existing object.

Basically, you violated the rule of 3.