# Calling the Constructor after Destructor in a Member Function

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, placement-new

Have a look at the `Reset` function below. I know calling constructors and destructors for `this` can be dangerous, but I really cannot find what is wrong when used as below. I'm asking this here because I couldn't find any related materials with Google. All I can find is that don't call the constructor within another constructor, and I obviously agree with that. But isn't it safe to call the constructor right after the destructor in a member function?

```
template<typename T>
class Array{
private:
    T* m_p;

    Array(const Array&);
    Array& operator=(const Array&);

public:
    Array(){
        m_p=0;
    }

    Array(int length):
    m_p(new T[length]){}

    ~Array(){
        delete[] m_p;
    }

    void Reset(int length){
        this->~Array();
        new(this) Array(length);
    }
};
```

Comment: related:[Can I get a fresh start in C++ without failing again?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8829548/33499)

Answer (score 1):

Even if your favorite implementation allows you to do such, it is still an extremely bad practice to do it.
What you need to consider is mainly 2 things:

> Object is not constructed properly until the constructor ends.
>
> Object should not be accessed after you call its destructor.

Playing tricks with constructor and destructor is not a good idea. They are there to introduce and remove the object respectively. Using them more than these roles indicates that your design is somewhat problematic. On the other side of the coin, member functions shouldn't call its object's destructor, either. Even if it works,  it is still a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
void Reset(int length){
    this->~Array();
    new(this) Array(length);
}
```

Is bad.

Why not

```
void Reset(int length) {
   delete[] m_p;
   m_p = new T[length];
}
```

or just use `std::vector`

Comment: `std::vector` is just too heavy to use in my case. So I'm asking 'why' is it bad?

Comment: 1. Why is it too "heavy"? 2. Getting that habit of calling constructors/destructor is just bad - You get unintended consequences (destructor/constructors do things behind the scenes like memory management).