# Is it valid to call destructor on 'this' and then assign a new value to 'this'?

Tags: c++, destructor, lifetime

Suppose I'm implementing some class `A` that has a `clear()` method that should set the object state to the "brand new" state as if it has just been created with a constructor:

- I should free all the resources that the current object is using (exactly the same thing `A::~A()` does),
- and then I should initialize those resources again (exactly the same thing `A::A()` does).

So my initial idea was as follows:

```
void A::clear() {
  this->~A();
  *this = A();
}
```

However, I was told that this code causes undefined behavior since I cannot dereference `this` after calling its destructor. But at the same time I was told a better idea as well: if we use placement new, there is no dereferencing, so this actually might work:

```
void A::clear() {
  this->~A();
  new (this) A();
}
```

This feels extremely uncomfortable and as error-prone as it gets... so is this code actually valid?

Comment: What do you mean by “extremely uncomfortable”? It’s the same amount of code as the (invalid) assignment. And yes, this is valid — unless the constructor of `A` throws, in which case you’re toast.

Comment: Your destructor should be calling a `clear()` function that does the "clearing", not the other way around.  Also, if the user really and truly wanted to set their object to a brand-new, clean slate, then let them explicitly do this, i.e. `A myA;...myA = {};` -- no need to hand-hold.

Comment: 1. What will happen if the constructor throws? 2. Can't you just do `*this = A();`?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is illegal in current C++ standard. However, I have heard that it was legal, in the very first draft of C++ language (1983), to assign to `this` and so this type of hack was possible.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh right, that's a fair point about "clearing". Also, in reality I have to implement a given interface that has a `clear()` method, so I can't make decisions on how to let the user interact with that class. That implies that `new (this) A();` line has to stay...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you should post your (2.) as an answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann I didn't because I'm not sure if the type is movable.

Comment: @prapin Huh? OP's assigning to `*this` not `this`, which is and always was legal (or would be legal if they weren't calling the destructor).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's fair, but I would observe that `*this = A();` is already being attempted.  You are only suggesting the removal of a destructor call.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124634/call-destructor-and-then-constructor-resetting-an-object.  it doesn't mention `this`, but a pointer to an object is a pointer to an object, so it should be the same answer.

Comment: There could be additional complications if `A` is a base class, as you'd be destroying and recreating the base object but not the derived part of the whole object.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, legal. There is an example in the C++ standard that does exactly this. But what happens if someone creates a class that’s derived from this one? Now, if the destructor works okay (i.e., it’s virtual, or they’re just unlucky), the code has transformed an object of the derived type into an object of the base type.

Comment: Wouldn't calling `this->~A()` formally invalidate any external pointers or references to that `a` object because the lifetime has formally ended? AFAIK only the result of `new` can refer to the newly constructed object, and old ones cannot. Even though the addresses will logically be the same, my understanding of the object model is that any maintained/held references will be invalidated -- and all old pointers would need to be rebound or `std::launder`ed

Comment: @Human-Compiler: No, it doesn't, as long as the replacement is of a complete object, and the new complete object has the same type as the old complete object.  Formerly there were restrictions on `const` and reference members, but those got removed.  See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8

Comment: "If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if "...

Answer (score 1):

> is this code actually valid?

Your code is valid.  It's also a rather unusual approach to merely **change** the object's value.

The assignment operator alone, if implemented correctly, will achieve this.

```
void A::clear() {
  *this = A();
}
```

If this code does not work as expected, your assignment operator has been incorrectly implemented.